# jsp scriplet text appears as is in jsp output when using custom tags

Tags: jsp, custom-tags, scriptlet

I have two custom tags mbar.tag and mitem.tag that are used as follows:-
test.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<% String sArg = request.getParameter("someparam"); %>
<mytags:mbar>
    <mytags:mitem title="images/<%= sArg %>-first.png"/>
    <mytags:mitem title="images/<%= sArg %>-second.png"/>
</mytags:mbar>
</body>
</html>
```

mbar tag evaluates to a  element
mitem tag evaluates to a  element with value of *title* as body of the  element
They are declared in a tld file

Output of test.jsp is

```
<html>
<body>
<% String sArg = request.getParameter("someparam"); %>
<div>
    <div>images/**<%= sArg %>**-first.png</div>
    <div>images/**<%= sArg %>**-second.png</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result contains the scriplet verbatim whereas I require the value of *sArg* to be substituted.
No errors are returned on screen. Seeing that jsp scriplets are supported in jsp, I am sure it is something to do with the custom tags. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use scriptlets. Never. Custom tags and the JSP EL have been introduced to be able to avoid scriptlets.

Use the JSP EL:

```
<mytags:mitem title="images/${param.someparam}-first.png"/>
```

And make sure that your tag's title tag is [declared as accepting runtime expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html#bnani), using

```
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
```

in the attribute declaration of the TLD file.

Comment: Sure, the jee5 tut also says that tag handlers should be used for custom tags, I was just experimenting with scriplets in custom tags.Ive tried your solution and it works well. Thanks.